# Bash script for toggle lenovo Vantage functionality in Ubuntu. Battery conservation in ubuntu for lenovo laptop

Tags: bash, scripts, lenovo

I am trying to write a bash function, to toggle battery conservation in a Lenovo laptop, like it does in windows.

However, it is giving the below command not found error, when I run, and it goes to the else part. please help me fix this if condition. var gets a 0 or 1 from the cat

**[1: command not found**

```
toggle_conservation () {
                var=$(cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode)                
                
                if [$var -eq 1]
        then
                sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode'
                echo "Conservation is off, bettery will charge upto 100%"
        else
                sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode'
                echo "Conservation is enabled, battery wont charge beyond 60-70%"
fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is working, had to add a condition in the if condition and remove preceding spaces.**

```
 toggle_conservation () {
    my_value=$(cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode)                
                    
    if [ $my_value -gt 0 ]
    then  
    # If variable equal to 1  
        sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode'
        echo "Conservation is off, bettery will charge upto 100%"
    else
        sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode'
        echo "Conservation is enabled, battery wont charge beyond 60-70%"
    fi 
    }
```